# New error after site moved

Tags: javascript, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

Below is the standard javaScript for a silverlight app. I am getting the `4004 error` at `throw new Error(errMsg);` `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. My main page works which is silverlight, but a sub folder used to run a diff app has this error when loading the default page. One thought was the connection string, but I have checked the specs and confirmed them with the host site and they agree with the format being correct. What else do I need to be looking at? The error in the IE console shows at `cTor` for one of my Child Windows constructors, but I have examined the code and see no problem and this code used to run fine before. Is there something on the new server that maybe missing I can talk to the hosting company about?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function onSilverlightError(sender, args) {
        var appSource = "";
        if (sender != null && sender != 0) {
            appSource = sender.getHost().Source;
        }

        var errorType = args.ErrorType;
        var iErrorCode = args.ErrorCode;

        if (errorType == "ImageError" || errorType == "MediaError") {
            return;
        }

        var errMsg = "Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application " + appSource + "\n";

        errMsg += "Code: " + iErrorCode + "    \n";
        errMsg += "Category: " + errorType + "       \n";
        errMsg += "Message: " + args.ErrorMessage + "     \n";

        if (errorType == "ParserError") {
            errMsg += "File: " + args.xamlFile + "     \n";
            errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
            errMsg += "Position: " + args.charPosition + "     \n";
        }
        else if (errorType == "RuntimeError") {
            if (args.lineNumber != 0) {
                errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
                errMsg += "Position: " + args.charPosition + "     \n";
            }
            errMsg += "MethodName: " + args.methodName + "     \n";
        }

        throw new Error(errMsg);//error here
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you cross verified the server control bindings? And can you show us the exact error description you are getting?

Comment: It is not throwing that error today. Now it is just sitting at 100% with the blue circles moving around it - without completing. About the binding - do you mean the part in the ClientConfig file?